# Dynamic NavigationLink destination in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have a View 'B' that has an initialiser that takes an argument.

```
struct B: View {
    let arg: Int

    init(arg: Int) {
        self.arg = arg
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("\(arg)")
    }
}
```

And I have a Navigation View 'A'.

'A' has one button, which when pressed, shows a popup where the user picks a number from 1-5. A closure of type `(Int) -> Void` is called with the chosen number.

```
struct A: View {
    @State var showPicker = false

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Button(action: { self.showPicker = true }) {
                Text("Pick Number")
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$showPicker, content: { 
                NumberPicker { number in 
                    *** Possible to navigate to B from here? ***
                } 
            })
        }
    }
}
```

**Question**
Is it possible to initialise view B with the result from the closure, and then navigate to it?

This used to be possible with `DynamicNavigationDestinationLink`, however Apple deprecated it and stated in the release notes that `NavigationLink` contains its capabilities now. I have searched through the docs, however, I have not been able to figure out how to use NavigationLink to produce the same outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new view with another navigationview where you can pick the number.

Here's a full code example how i would approach this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct viewA: View {

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            NavigationLink(destination: viewC()) {
                Text("Pick Number")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct viewB: View {

    @Binding var showSheet: Bool
    @Binding var arg: Int

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach((1...5), id: \.self) {number in
                    Button(action: {
                        self.arg = number
                        self.showSheet.toggle()
                    }) {
                        Text("\(number)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct viewC: View {

    @State var showSheet:Bool = true
    @State var arg: Int = 0

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("\(arg)")
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $showSheet) {
            viewB(showSheet: self.$showSheet, arg: self.$arg)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work on iPad which is my target device. The navigation happens in the sheet, however the sheet doesn't take up the whole screen on iPad.

Comment: And you need the number picker to take up the whole screen? Or is it that viewB is not visible at first and you have to swipe before you can pick the number? 
If it’s the latter you can use the .navigationViewStyle(StackNavigationViewStyle()) modifier on viewB

Comment: @Lifaen I've used a number picker here to simplify the problem. Using view names from your answer; The number picker (viewB) shouldn't take up the whole screen. The navigation in your example is happening inside viewB which only takes up a portion of the screen. I want the navigation to happen inside viewA based on the number picked in viewB.

Comment: So you want to open a sheet for viewB but than the sheet closes and it navigates to viewC, right?

Comment: I've edited my original answer, this could be a possible way.